# Visual Studio Express or SharpDevelop

Tags: visual-studio-express, sharpdevelop

What is better to use, Visual Studio Express or SharpDevelop, and why?

Comment: Consider revising your question. Define what is "better" to you. "Better to transition into a commercial IDE solution" will get you different answers from "better open source support."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature comparison: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/articles/VisualStudioExpressComparison.aspx

Personally, since they are both free, I'd opt for the one by the authors of C# and .NET, Visual Studio Express.